# Смена языка приложения winforms в рантайме

Tags: c#

Есть приложение у которого для каждой формы есть Resource-файлы для разных языков - EN, DE, RU и тд.

Сейчас язык выбирается автоматически в зависимости от культуры активной для системы. То есть в немецком виндовсе - автоматически загрузятся немекцкие ресурсы, а в русском - русские и тд.

Хочется дать возможность пользователю в меню выбрать язык. То есть что бы он в меню кликнул на "Английский" и ррраааз - все надписи на всех элементах поменялись.

Как это лучше сделать? Какой правильный путь?

Пока чего-то не выходит у меня. Культуру меняю а все надписи остаются старыми. Перезагружать форму (что бы выполнилась ф-ия InitializeComponent() ) и терять данные не хочется.

Писать функцию в которой всем нужным св-вам нужных элементов присваиваются тексты из соответствующего культуре ресурса - лениво. Есть другой, более автоматический, способ? Подозреваю что нет, но вдруг....

Comment: Посмотри вот этот проект: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8980/Instantly-Changing-Language-in-the-Form

Comment: Вам придется менять не только надписи. В большинстве, случаев кроме надписей, может потребоваться замена размеров элементов, форматирования отображаемого текста, шрифта и его параметров, в особо тяжких случаях - замена компоновки контролов. Я не знаю ваш проект и, возможно, все это вас не коснется, но иметь ввиду однозначно стоит. А по поводу потери данных при пересоздании формы - так не держите бизнес-логику в контролах, не место ей там, и терять ни чего не придется.

Answer (score 0):

Для изменения языка пользователю и обновления всех надписей на форме существуют несколько подходов. Один из распространенных способов - использование класса ResourceManager для загрузки соответствующих ресурсов в зависимости от выбранного языка. Вот как можно сделать:

Создайте ресурсные файлы для каждого языка (EN, DE, RU и т.д.). Убедитесь, что они имеют одинаковые имена, но различные расширения (например, Resources.resx, Resources.de.resx, Resources.ru.resx).

В вашем коде добавьте глобальную переменную, которая будет хранить выбранный язык, например:

```
private static string currentLanguage = "en"; // По умолчанию - английский
```

Создайте функцию, которая будет загружать соответствующие ресурсы для выбранного языка и обновлять текстовые значения элементов на форме. Например:

```
private void UpdateLanguage()
{
    ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(typeof(Resources)); // Передайте тип ресурса, который содержит строки для формы
    CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(currentLanguage);

    // Обновление текстовых значений элементов на форме
    label1.Text = rm.GetString("Label1Text", ci);
    button1.Text = rm.GetString("Button1Text", ci);
    // Добавьте остальные элементы, которые требуют обновления текста
}
```

В обработчике события выбора языка, например, при щелчке на пункте меню "Английский", установите выбранный язык и вызовите функцию UpdateLanguage(), чтобы обновить текстовые значения на форме:

```
private void englishToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    currentLanguage = "en"; // Установите выбранный язык на английский
    UpdateLanguage(); // Обновите текстовые значения элементов на форме
}
```

Таким образом, при выборе языка из меню будет установлен соответствующий код языка (currentLanguage) и вызвана функция UpdateLanguage(), которая загрузит ресурсы для выбранного языка и обновит текстовые значения элементов на форме.

Обратите внимание, что вы должны заменить Label1Text, Button1Text и другие строки на фактические идентификаторы строк в ваших ресурсных файлах. Также, убедитесь, что ресурсные файлы правильно настроены и содержат переводы для соответствующих языков.

Comment: [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

Comment: :-) такое себе.

Answer (score 0):

Тоже задумывался над этим вопросом. А нужно ли, чтобы эта функция была доступна в любое время: "То есть что бы он в меню кликнул на "Английский" и ррраааз - все надписи на всех элементах поменялись"? Это относится к глобальным настройкам, и менять их нужно только тогда, когда никакая бизнес логика не в работе. Нужно продумать сценарий использования этой функции. Допустим, пользователь запускает приложение, выбирает нужный язык и начинает работать. Тут с реализацией всё ясно и она достаточно простая.

А если хочется зачем-то (зачем?) менять язык на лету, то над этим придётся потрудиться ручками. Процесс можно автоматизировать: перебрать все элементы управления (ЭУ), менять свойство Text, а для каких-то определённых ЭУ и другие свойства в зависимости от класса ЭУ. Можно даже INotifyPropertyChanged использовать, привязка таким же образом.